# how to send array in rest api php

Tags: php, arrays, rest, api

i want to send array with rest api in php but i don't know how to do this

i tried with json and without json but not response to me

```php
$drv = array('mobile'=>'+123456', 'title'=>"MR", 'firstName_en'=>'john', 'lastName_en'=>'wilet');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "checkoutStation=xxx&checkoutDate=20190826&checkoutTime=0900&checkinStation=xxx&checkinDate=20190827&checkinTime=0900&email=info@site.net&driver=$drv");
```

also try

```php
$drv = array('mobile'=>'+123456', 'title'=>"MR", 'firstName_en'=>'john', 'lastName_en'=>'wilet');
$drv=json_encode($drv);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "checkoutStation=xxx&checkoutDate=20190826&checkoutTime=0900&checkinStation=xxx&checkinDate=20190827&checkinTime=0900&email=info@site.net&driver=$drv");
```

because driver parameter required a array data value
when i run my codes return errors":["Error in driver data!"] to me

Comment: Is that an API you created? If so then show the part that accepts the data if not then a link to the docs of that API will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

you need to build query string using parameters array

```
$params = array(
        'checkoutStation' => 'xxx',
        'checkoutDate' => '20190826',
        'checkoutTime' => '0900',
        'checkinStation' => 'xxx',
        'checkinDate' => '20190827',
        'checkinTime' => '0900',
        'email' => 'info@site.net',
        'driver' => array(
            'mobile'=>'+123456',
            'title'=>"MR", 
            'firstName_en'=>'john', 
            'lastName_en'=>'wilet'
        )
    );
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
```

Comment: Actually i have a multi Parameters and i use     curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "checkoutStation=xxx&checkoutDate=20190826&checkoutTime=0900&checkinStation=xxx&checkinDate=20190827&checkinTime=0900&email=info@site.net&driver=$drv");

Answer (score 1):

```php
$data=array('mobile'=>'+123456','title'=>"MR",'firstName'=>'john','lastName'=>'wilet');
$drv=json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "&driver=$drv");
```

Comment: if you read my comment i also tried your comment to.. i use with json already ...

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it